# Unable to save test plan in jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I tried to save test plan in Jmeter but always shows an error like this [image: unsaved]. I am using Java 8 [image: Java 8] and tried to change Look and Feel to "Window"
Anyone can help me with this?? Many Thanks.

should not show error??

Answer (score 0):

Normal users don't have access to `Program Files` folder, the options are in:

1. Run JMeter [as administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/shell-experience/use-run-as-start-app-admin)
2. Grant your user [write access](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-ed/000137238/understanding-file-and-folder-permissions-in-windows?lwp=rt) to the folder where JMeter is installed
3. Move your JMeter installation to i.e. your [home folder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory) where you have the full control

Also there are 3 errors in the [jmeter.log file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) so it worth checking out what else is wrong.